# Strange â character in curl dom utf8 htmlspecialchars not working

Tags: php, curl, utf-8

I have a strange character â appearing instead of quotes and double quotes in the curl request

```
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
```

I'm using php domelement to manipulate the result

```
$fulltext = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p');
foreach($fulltext as $para) {
  $fulltextstr .= $para->textContent;
}
```

It works for the most part except quotes and doublequotes are replaced with â, how do i replace this.

I've tried

echo htmlspecialchars($fulltextstr,ENT_SUBSTITUTE,'UTF-8');

but this doesn't remove the characters, is there any way to clean the output either by replacing or if that's not possible then removing these characters!?

It's having this issue fetching this link:
https://www.dissentmagazine.org/article/coping-economy-mindfulness-goes-corporate

**MORE DETAILS**

I have set utf-8 in the meta headers and i'm using

```
mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

The site header is set to UTF-8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

What else should I DO?!

Comment: What are you using to display your PHP output? It may be that your browser is getting incorrect encoding headers or that your terminal uses the wrong encoding. The character is (I believe) a UTF-8 character.

Comment: I've updated the question with the utf8 settings. Is there something I'm missing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `“` character detects as UTF-8 and seems fine, I'm seeing similar issues to what you describe though.
While this is not a **perfect** answer it is a work-around.

You can simply replace those characters (and other specific characters) before using the string.

```
str_replace(
    [
        "\xe2\x80\x98", 
        "\xe2\x80\x99", 
        "\xe2\x80\x9c", 
        "\xe2\x80\x9d", 
        "\xe2\x80\x93", 
        "\xe2\x80\x94", 
        "\xe2\x80\xa6"
    ], 
    [
        "'", 
        "'", 
        '"', 
        '"', 
        '-', 
        '--', 
        '...'
    ], 
    $text
);
```

This would replace the left and right quote with just a quote, the left and right double quote with just a double quote, and the hyphen, dash and ellipse characters with matching symbols.

Comment: Thanks I'm hoping for a better approach but this will have to do.

Comment: It doesn't seem be working. It's not finding these character codes in the string. I tried using the individual codes and they don't match the characters in the string. Any ideas on alternates or how to find the actual character codes?

Comment: Okay I found something, utf8_decode fixes the output but that would mean my site isn't using utf8.. how do i find this out.. the issue with utf8_decode is it replaces &nbsp; with black ? diamond characters.

Comment: I found the string was being appended to an ASCII string which made the output ASCII. I still have to use utf8_decode on the original utf8 string to clean the output however which is strange as it should just display properly.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to patch it up, this produces clean output, the first line is to remove an "&nbsp" character which was being shown as a black diamond question mark.

```
$str = str_replace("\xc2\xa0",' ',$str);
$str = utf8_decode($str);
```

This isn't a robust solution as I was expecting the original utf8 to display properly but have found that if I have to use utf8_decode then my site isn't properly utf8... how do I fix this?! I'm setting the utf8 in the headers meta and i've used mb_regex_encoding('UTF-8') and mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8') and the database is also utf8, what else am I missing?!

Comment: ... Aren't you asking a new question here? That is not what the box with the huge label "Your Answer" is for.

Comment: True. Its the solution i'm using and was hoping someone will tell me a better one. I found the site is utf8 but the string was being appended to an ASCII string before output. I'm still having to use the utf8_decode to clean up the original utf8 string though which is confusing.